# Definition of Convex Set

Tags: metric-spaces, convex-analysis, connectedness

The definition given in my textbook for a convex set is; "Let $E$ be a subset of $\Bbb R^n$. We say $E$ is convex if given $x,y \in E$, $(1-t)x +ty \in E$ for all real numbers $t$ with $0\le t\le 1$."

My doubt are:

- Technically is the definition also valid if we take $tx+(1-t)y \in E$ instead of $(1-t)x + ty \in E$? To me it appears so. Is it just convention or is there a catch that I am not able to see?
- Since $E$ is subset of $\Bbb R^n$ why are we considering only $x$ and $y$ (because then shouldn't this definition be for $\Bbb R^2$)?

Comment: Concerning the first question: yes, you are right and no, there is no catch. Concerning the last question: how do you pass from $x,y\in E$ to the idea that this holds only on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Yes, also valid. You can also go for $E$ is convex if it contains $\{rx+sy\mid r,s\in[0,1]\wedge r+s=1\}$ for each pair $x,y\in E$. Considering only pairs is enough. Based on that you can prove that a convex set $E\subseteq\mathbb R^2$  also contains triangle $\{rx+sy+tz\mid r,s,t\in[0,1]\wedge r+s+t=1\}$ if $x,y,z\in E$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you substitute $t$ with $1-t$, you arrive at $(1-t)x+ty$ instead of $tx+(1-t)y$, and $0\le 1-t\le 1$ is equivalent to $0\le t\le 1$.
A more symmetric way of definingt convexity might be to demand $tx+uy\in E$ for all $t,u\ge0$ with $t+u=1$.

Here, $x$ and $y$ are not the two coordinates of a single point $(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2$. Instead, they are elements of $E$ (and hence of $\Bbb R^n$.
If you wish, view $x$ as $(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ and $y$ as $(y_1,\ldots, y_n)$ and write $tx+(1-t)y$ clumsily as $\bigl(tx_1+(1-t)y_1,\ldots, tx_n+(1-z)y_n\bigr)$.

Answer (score 1):

A convex set is a set with the property, said in words:
*If you take two points in this set, then the straight line connecting them lies in the set.*

This is the answer to one of your questions, why you only take *two* points $x$ and $y$. These are the two arbitrary points you take as the ends of your straight line.

The other point is that is is certainly equivalent if you say
$$ tx + (1-t)y \in E \ \forall t \in [0,1] $$ or
$$ (1-t)x + ty \in E \ \forall t \in [0,1]. $$ 
Why is this equivalent? Well, because if you have the first property and take some $t \in [0,1]$, then just define $s = (1-t)$ and for $s$ we then have $ (1-s)x + sy \in E$. In this way, you can transform one description into the other.

Comment: I suggest to replace the word "line" with "line segment".

Comment: Thank you to everyone. I have understood the definition, including as to why we consider only x and y